# Подскажите , почему z-index не работает?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В общем, есть такая структура html:

```
        <div>
            <div id="test1">
                 <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-9 search-results">
                    <div class="search-result" *ngFor="let assembly of searchResult">{{assembly.name}}</div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div id="test2"></div>
        </div>
```

Вешаю вот такой CSS:

```
#test1{
     position: relative;
     z-index: 9999;
}

#test2{
     position: relative;
     z-index: -1;
}
```

Полагая, что мои результаты поиска будут перекрывать блок внизу, но ничего не происходит.

`div` с `id="test1"` просто растягивается по высоте смещая нижний блок вниз.

Подскажите, что я упускаю? Chrome не меню разработки не показывает перекрытия стилей.

Если нужна еще какая-нибудь информация, то я готов ее предоставить.

Вот более полный пример

```css
body {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#search-component {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#additional-panel {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* background-color: darkgrey; */
  border: 0.1px solid silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#additional-panel>.form-group.row {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.search-result {
  border: 10px aqua;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-results {
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.search-result:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.search-result:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

#test1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#test2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div id="test1">
    <div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="search" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Поиск</label>
        <input name="search" class="col-sm-8 form-control" [(ngModel)]="dataToSearch.assemblyName" />
        <button class="col-sm-1" (click)="onSearchClick()">искать</button>
      </div>
      <div id="additional-panel" class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-9" *ngIf="!isColapsed">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-2" for="description">Описание</label>
          <input class="form-control col-sm-5" id="description" name="Description" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-9" (click)="isColapsed=!isColapsed">Дополнительные параметры</button>
              <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-9 search-results">
          <div class="search-result">1</div>
          <div class="search-result">1</div>
          <div class="search-result">1</div>
          <div class="search-result">1</div>
          <div class="search-result">1</div>
          <div class="search-result">1</div>
          <div class="search-result">1</div>
          <div class="search-result">1</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="test2">
      Контент
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: элементы должны быть на одном уровне иерархии для того чтобы работал z-index

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а то, что 2 div'а имеют одного родителя - этого не достаточно? Вроде, 1 уровень иерархии, нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно это решить за счет абсолютного позиционирования второго элемента и явного указания `top:50px`, вот так:

```css
body {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#search-component {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#additional-panel {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* background-color: darkgrey; */
  border: 0.1px solid silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#additional-panel>.form-group.row {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.search-result {
  border: 10px aqua;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-results {
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color:white
}

.search-result:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.search-result:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

#test1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#test2 {
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color:wheat;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div id="test1">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="search" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Поиск</label>
      <input name="search" class="col-sm-8 form-control" [(ngModel)]="dataToSearch.assemblyName" />
      <button class="col-sm-1" (click)="onSearchClick()">искать</button>
    </div>
    <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-9 search-results">
      <div class="search-result">1</div>
      <div class="search-result">1</div>
      <div class="search-result">1</div>
      <div class="search-result">1</div>
      <div class="search-result">1</div>
      <div class="search-result">1</div>
      <div class="search-result">1</div>
      <div class="search-result">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="test2">
    Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент<br>
    Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент<br>
    Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент<br>
    Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент<br>
    Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент<br>
    Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Малость дополнил код. Там еще сверху должен быть инпут с кнопкой, которые не должны наезжать. Наезжатьдолжны именно результаты.

Comment: @iluxa1810 тогда вот можно указать отступ вручную

Comment: Вроде, работает, но растягивание элементов по ширине пропадает...=(

Comment: @iluxa1810 добавил ширину

Comment: Адаптивность бутстрапа все таки ломается=(

Comment: наверное надо сделать контейнер, который появляется, после этой иерархии

Comment: Кстати, а почему перекрытие работает с абсолютным позиционированием? Так то в документации написано, что с относительным тоже все должно работать.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вот, гляьте статейку, главное уровень вложенности и наличие позиционирования - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Еще вопрос: Допустим, внизу верхнего блока будет кнопка, которая будет открывать блок дополнительных параметров для поиска, но я не хочу, что бы она перекрывала блок снизу. Что я могу сделать в этом случае? Сейчас происходит перекрытие=( Хочу, что бы перекрывали именно только результаты поиска.

Comment: @iluxa1810 надо codepen хотя бы или syncfiddle, только если sync то попозже, я сейчас с телефона

Comment: Обновил. Есть кнопка, которая открывает внизу меню. Это меню не должно перекрывать блок снизу, а должно его сдвинуть. А вот резульаты поиска должны перекрывать.

Comment: В общем, разобрался. В результаты поиска первого блока добавил класс, которые задает абсолютную позицию. 2 внешних блока даже не пришлось править.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну да, я это и имел в виду

Answer (score 2):

Элементы должны быть на одном уровне иерархии для того чтобы работал z-index

---

Не понятно почему или  что у Вас не работает, тут ведь все верно? первый идет надо вторым:

```css
#test1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#test2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: blue;
  top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <div id="test1">
                 <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-9 search-results">
                    <div class="search-result" *ngFor="let assembly of searchResult">{{assembly.name}}</div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div id="test2">1</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: А перекрытие можно сделать только через z-index, да?

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну или порядком следования элементов, последний сверху

Comment: Касательно примера разметки. Т.е test2 должен быть вложен в test1? Просто смущает не закрытый div сверху, как будто что-то потерялось...

Comment: @iluxa1810 это мой косяк, я тут с телефона пишу, через минут 15 починю))

Comment: @iluxa1810 а я ведь наврал, у Вас корректная разметка, просто Вы кривовато ее сюда запостили

Comment: @iluxa1810 сори за дезинформацию, посмотрите сниппет, тут все работает...

Comment: т е разметка норм? А бутстрап не может мне мешать? Там я использую несколько классов

Comment: Row и form-group юзабельна

Comment: @iluxa1810 а есть где глянуть?

Comment: Через минут 20 кину.

Comment: обновил вопрос.